# Does ubuntu allow users to run ESET Smart Security?

Tags: security, antivirus, malware

Does ubuntu allow users to run ESET Smart Security? I am considering upgrading ubuntu from Windows 7 but I'm not sure if it allows the use of outside security programs.

Comment: what do you need in terms of security? You know a Windows virus wont work on Ubuntu if you don't install wine or run windows software in some meaning...

Comment: Might work @Alvar - http://www.eset.co.uk/Home/NOD32-Antivirus-Linux

Comment: The OP was asking if they could get this Smart security thing for Linux - apparently the might be able to... Or atleast something similar @Alvar. There is probably no need for it, but they can...

Comment: @wilf so instead of saying yes you can, you should say you can, but you really don't have to...

Comment: @Alvar, I did not 'yes you can', I said it 'might work'

Comment: @Alvar I think my answer compress everything we think about malware and windows ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the Windows version of ESet Smart Security. The first thing to consider is that ESET smart security is made to run on windows. Software made for one OS generally doesn't run on other OS.

But there is an exception. A software compatability layer called **Wine** has been written for linux which allows you to run Windows software in linux. You can run many windows software & games using it. However not all windows software works.

Antiviruses, firewalls and sandbox software don't generally run well under wine. Trust me I've tried.

**However** you can use antiviruses made for linux. ESET has http://www.eset.co.uk/Home/NOD32-Antivirus-Linux . There are also [Comodo for linux](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php) and Bitdefender.

There is also the free "Clam TK".

**Imp:** You don't have to remove Windows 7 to install Ubuntu. You can dual boot them.

**Note:** Also linux IMHO doesn't need an antivirus. Not many viruses have been made for linux and also linux has a more secure environment. Linux malware are extremely rare.

Answer (score 0):

For most Linux distributions you do not need anti-virus software - but you can get Linux ones, like [ClamAV](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV), which will run on Ubuntu.

There is a page on the eset site - http://www.eset.co.uk/Home/NOD32-Antivirus-Linux - which says it will run on Linux, but I don't know how.

You don't really need to have anitvirus software for Ubuntu and other Linux systems, as it has so little market share against other systems like Windows and Mac OS, meaning that virus writers would not gain much from them.

[image]

Also, Linux is much better security wise than systems like Windows, which seems to have the security holes built in. Viruses, and other forms of malware can still pose a threat, the same with all computer systems, but not as much as would be posed to Windows or Mac.

There is [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/135392/htg-explains-why-you-dont-need-an-antivirus-on-linux-and-when-you-do/) which explains this some more.

Answer (score 0):

Lets put things clear:

1. ESET Antivirus (the **Windows version**) wouldn't do any good in your Linux.
2. Linux has a poor compatibility with malware and a high security scheme by default, from the first moment you boot up, that makes it unlikely target for virus.
3. The only reason why using an antivirus in linux is to not allow spreading of malicious files to windows systems, that is, to help stop virus from infecting virus systems.
4. You can't (or is too difficult for being feasible) run a Realtime Windows Antivirus on Linux using Wine. Wine is just a compatibility layer meant to allow certain windows programs to run in linux, it won't make your system magically run windows applications as if it were native.

Bottom line:

You **can** have an antivirus in Linux, you must if you share files with Windows, you shouldn't install a Windows antivirus in Linux, you could be more at peace if you think things calmly.

Comment: I disagree with you. Wine is indeed magic. How else can it make linux run Windows programs. LOL!

Comment: @ufoguy Unicorns are magic, wine is just good programming.

Comment: well you dont need a antivirus on a Ubuntu if you just share files with a windows computer. Then the Windows computer will have a antivirus anyways so it's not really a problem...

Comment: @Alvar: With your logic unicorns can be programmed too. Once you reverse engineer Horse DNA which is propeitary. Also, the followers of Horse's creator are taking extreme measures like murder, laws etc. to prevent reverse engineering of DNA and preventing people from making unicorns. Some people think microsoft is evil? Think of this!

Comment: @ufoguy you are the most random off topic dude I've met all week, just sayin^^